# TouchID Module - Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-1001 \"Unknown policy: '0'\"

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-modules, appcelerator-modules

I am using the following [TouchID Module (Version 2.1.0)](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.touchid/releases/tag/ios-2.1.0) with SDK 5.5.1.GA. But the issue is that when I am calling the isSupported() function with deviceCanAuthenticate(), I am getting the following error:

> message = "Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-1001 \"Unknown policy: '0'\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown policy: '0'}";

The code that I am using is:

```
if (!TiTouchId.isSupported() || !TiTouchId.deviceCanAuthenticate().canAuthenticate) {
    alert("You cannot use this feature");
}
```

But if I swap the function calls, that is like this, then I do not get the error:

```
if (!TiTouchId.deviceCanAuthenticate().canAuthenticate || !TiTouchId.isSupported()) {
    alert("You cannot use this feature");
}
```

I am not sure as to why it is behaving in such a manner. I have loaded the module in alloy.js so that I can access it from any controller.

I am testing it in iOS Simulator 9.3 and also on iPhone 6 Plus device with iOS 10.2. On both the case I am getting the error. Is anyone facing this issue?

Comment: what happens when you only call : TiTouchId.isSupported() ?

Comment: In that case too it gives the error.

Comment: According to the module's doc, the module requires ti sdk 6.0.0.GA

Comment: Here you can find a full example for iOS https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.touchid/blob/master/ios/example/app.js

Comment: May be you forgot to set the authentication policy through setAuthenticationPolicy

Comment: Yes. Setting the authentication policy resolved it. If you mentioned it as an answer I can mark it. Also, the minSDK defined in the module is 5.5.1.GA, so I think we can use it with 5.5.1.GA and use it.

Comment: You can provide the answer and accept it your self no worries ;) glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to call setAuthenticationPolicy and pass the information. Once that is done, then the issue gets resolved. (@TheFuquan provided the resolution)

Comment: i have same problem , what do u mean by setAuthenticationPolicy?